# Nested std::maps

Tags: c++, stl

Supposed I have a type I'll call NamedNestedMap

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, NamedNestedMap> >
```

In this case each second (value) of the pair is the same kind or type as the parent object.  What I can't figure out is how to declare it.  This will allows a recursive algorithm to walk down thru the "tree" of maps.

The Value type is the same as the parent type, which at the point I need to reference it, isn't fully declared.

How do you declare something nested like this...

I can't even typedef the first one so that I can include it the second because it's incomplete

The recursion would look for something in the map, when it finds it, recurse on the value of that object.  The algorithm part seems pretty straight forward, the declaration part is the stumper here.  I'm not trying to iterate the map of maps, just use the map.find, recurse and use map.find again.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think your compiler might explode if you continue along this line of reasoning. What would be the type of an iterator on that class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to use pointers (naturally, since otherwise the recursion will never terminate - you'll always need one more empty map):

```
struct NestedMap;
struct NestedMap : std::map<std::string, NestedMap*> {};
```

Naturally, you'd probably want to use `shared_ptr` or something like that to manage memory, rather than raw pointers.

Comment: From what I've heard, inheriting STL class is a bad thing.

Comment: It's not inherently bad. The problem is that STL classes don't have virtual destructors, so you can't use such inherited classes polymorphically (you'll get wrong destructors to execute if you delete via a pointer to base). So long as you don't try to use polymorphism, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @PavelMinaev I know I'm pretty late for question, but is there anyway to use std::vector here? It seems to give me error `no operator "[]" matches these operands` when nesting maps with std::variant.

Answer (score 6):

Create a struct representing a node.

```
struct Node {
    std::map<std::string, Node *> children;
};
```

You can, of course, make it a class and hide the data and such.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to have a nested map of depth n:

```
template<class key_type, class val_type, int nest_depth>
struct nest
{
typedef std::map<key_type, typename nest<key_type, val_type, 
                nest_depth-1>::map_type> map_type;
};

template<class key_type, class val_type>
struct nest<key_type, val_type, 0>
{
    typedef std::map<key_type, val_type> map_type;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
nest<std::string, std::string, 2> nested_map;
```

Comment: If I understand his question correctly, he wants a truly recursive data structure (essentially, a tree), so `n` would be `+INF`, so to speak.

Comment: Ok, i didn't think of that. I thought of depth n as he tried to declare it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a recursive structure.

The best you could probably do is have a map of map of pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
class Node {
    ...

    std::map<std::string, Node*> children;
}
```

Here, each `Node` has a map of "children" in a map, and this children can have children, and so-on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your type definition for `NamedNestedMap` has no termination in its recursive structure.  The template expansion for `NamedNestedMap` will be infinite and thus there is no way represent it in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you present it, and you probably don't want to.
The reason for this is that pairs in the map are stored by value.
Do you want your whatever name-value table be copied into another container?
I would go for a wrapper along the lines @strager and Pavel are proposing,
optionally using smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to compile for me:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct RecMap
{
    std::map<std::string, RecMap> m;
};

int main()
{
    RecMap rec;
    rec.m["first"] = RecMap();
    rec.m["first"].m["second"] = RecMap();
}
```

Not 100% sure if it is legal (e.g can you have a class X that contains a `vector<X>` as a member?). The recursion isn't really infinite here, since eventually you'll run into a RecMap containing an empty map.

Edit: [this article](http://www.ddj.com/database/184403814) discusses the situation. Conclusion: undefined. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that creating a recursive structure can bring you problems. Just use normal maps, like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, map<string, string> > nest;
    nest["first"]["second"] = "Hello nest!";
    printf("%s\n", nest["first"]["second"].c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the execution:

```
$ g++ ./nest.cpp -o nest.out -ansi -pedantic -std=c++98
$ ./nest.out
Hello nest!
$
```